# Why do some official Nix Docker containers not have the `nixos-rebuild` command?

Tags: nix, nixos

The following official Nix Docker containers don't have the `nixos-rebuild` command:

- [`nixos/nix`](https://hub.docker.com/r/nixos/nix)
- [`nixpkgs/nix-unstable`](https://hub.docker.com/r/nixpkgs/nix-unstable)

**Is there something missing from these instances of NixOS?**

**`nixos/nix`**:

```bash
$ docker run --tty --interactive 'nixos/nix'
bash-5.1# nixos-rebuild
bash: nixos-rebuild: command not found
```

**`nixpkgs/nix-unstable`**:

```bash
$ docker run --tty --interactive 'nixpkgs/nix-unstable'
bash-5.2# nixos-rebuild
bash: nixos-rebuild: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `nixos-rebuild` is from Nixos and not Nix.

The name of the docker image is a bit confusing as the parent/user is `nixos` in (`nixos/nix`).

It's also why you wont' find a nixos related configuration.nix file either in the image (as asked here: [Where is the Nixos configuration located for the nix image on dockerhub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169279/where-is-the-nix-configuration-located-for-the-nix-image-on-dockerhub)).

There seems to be some issues with running Nixos in a docker container according to [GitHub issue: NixOS/nixpkgs: Running NixOS inside Docker #2878](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/2878), so likely you'll need a VM instead if you want do some testing.

---

However, you can build a Nixos configuration using the nix container. Something along the lines of:

`nix-build '<nixpkgs/nixos>' -A config.system.build.isoImage -I nixos-config=configuration-iso.nix`

The above command builds an ISO from the specified configuration-iso.nix. And will dump the contents into a `result/` directory from where the command is run.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to replace Docker containers with `systemd-nspawn` instances on Mac OS. I was trying to run a single Docker container of actual NixOS, then use the `nixos-container` wrapper to spawn `systemd-nspawn` containers either imperatively or with the declarative configuration file. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you plan to run in the containers? You can cuse nix to build docker containers, or use nix within docker and run a nix built executable.  However if you need a full system nixos for running systemd services or something else, then I think that's where it gets tricky. Probably best to ask in another question post though.